# How to prevent an Optional parameter from taking an OptionsPattern parameter without multiple function definitions?

Tags: function-construction, options, optional-arguments

I have function the needs to enable some `Optional` parameters and an `OptionsPattern`.  The issue I am facing is that the options are being matched to the optional parameters when the optional parameters are excluded.

How do I specify that the optional parameters should use their default when not provided without making multiple function definitions.

With

```
ClearAll[f]
f[ts_, maxError_, fitAlgorithm_: LinearModelFit, algorithmParams_: {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 <|"fitAlgorithm" -> fitAlgorithm, "algorithmParams" -> algorithmParams, "opts" -> {opts}|>
```

Then all optional defaults and no options works.

```
f[1, 2]
```

> ```
> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> LinearModelFit, "algorithmParams" -> {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, "opts" -> {}|>
> ```

However, any additional parameters are misinterpreted

```
f[1, 2, StepMonitor :> (a = # &)]
```

> ```
> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> StepMonitor :> (a = #1 &), "algorithmParams" -> {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, "opts" -> {}|>
> ```

The `StepMonitor` option should be the first item in `opts`. Instead it is taken to be the `fitAlgorithm` parameter.

I know multiple function defintions will work. For example:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[ts_, maxError_, fitAlgorithm_, algorithmParams_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 <|"fitAlgorithm" -> fitAlgorithm, "algorithmParams" -> algorithmParams, "opts" -> {opts}|>
f[ts_, maxError_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 f[ts, maxError, LinearModelFit, {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, opts]
f[ts_, maxError_, fitAlgorithm_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 f[ts, maxError, fitAlgorithm, {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, opts]
```

But this is not actually creating optional parameters with default values.

Comment: Sorry for delay with closing ;) And of course let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Kuba Nope. You are on point. I searched for "OptionsPattern Optional" and that question does not appear in the resulting list.

Comment: It is usually easier if you know the answer, here `Except + OptionQ`, but it should not work that way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Except[_?OptionQ]` can be a general way to go:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[ts_, maxError_
, fitAlgorithm : Except[_?OptionQ] : LinearModelFit
, algorithmParams : Except[_?OptionQ] : {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}
, opts : OptionsPattern[]
] := <|
  "fitAlgorithm" -> fitAlgorithm
, "algorithmParams" -> algorithmParams
, "opts" -> {opts}
|>


f[1, 2, StepMonitor :> (a = # &)]
```

> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> LinearModelFit, 
>    "algorithmParams" -> {[FormalX], [FormalX]}, 
>    "opts" -> {StepMonitor :> (a = #1 &)}|>

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using just a default, also include a pattern. For example:

```
ClearAll[f]
Options[f] = {"a"->"b"};

f[
    ts_,
    maxError_,
    fitAlgorithm_Symbol:LinearModelFit,
    algorithmParams:{__Symbol}:{\[FormalX],\[FormalX]},
    opts:OptionsPattern[]
] := <|"fitAlgorithm"->fitAlgorithm,"algorithmParams"->algorithmParams,"opts"->{opts}|>
```

Then the following does what you want:

```
f[1, 2, "a"->"c"]
f[1, 2, {x, y}, "a"->"d"]
f[1, 2, fooFit, "a"->"e"]
f[1, 2, fooFit, {x, y}, "a"->"f"]
```

> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> LinearModelFit, 
>    "algorithmParams" -> {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, "opts" -> {"a" -> "c"}|>
>
> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> LinearModelFit, "algorithmParams" -> {x, y}, 
>    "opts" -> {"a" -> "d"}|>
>
> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> fooFit, "algorithmParams" -> {\[FormalX], \[FormalX]}, 
>    "opts" -> {"a" -> "e"}|>
>
> <|"fitAlgorithm" -> fooFit, "algorithmParams" -> {x, y}, 
>    "opts" -> {"a" -> "f"}|>